# Where are pages files stored after I export them to itunes?

Tags: itunes, pages, ipad

With my iPad connected to my MacBook, I exported some Pages files to iTunes in docx format. Now I'm using my laptop without the iPad, and I want to find these files. Where/how are they stored? Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that get exported to iTunes on iOS don't automatically transfer to iTunes the next time you sync.

A manual step is required: select the device in iTunes, then click the Apps tab and scroll to the bottom of the page. The **file transfer** section is where you pick Pages and then place a copy of the exported file onto your computer's file system.

Apple has a longer article with step by step instructions and pictures:

- [iWork for iOS: About iTunes File Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4088)

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2 step process:

1/ mark the files to transfer (Export) to iTunes while in Pages on the iPad,

2/ once the iPad is connected, transfer the files from the IPad to the Mac.

I fear you did not do step #2.

In Pages on the iPad, Export in .docx (or .pdf and .pages) format. This creates the file in the selected format and makes the file *visible* to the iTunes interface on the Mac.

When the iPad is then connected in iTunes, go to the Apps tab > File Sharing section at the very bottom and select the Pages app & its documents. Select a filename or filenames from the list of files. Once selected, you must click the **Save to...** button to pull up a save dialog. You can then save wherever you like - local or external HD, networked NAS, webDAV server, USB key - whatever.

**NOTE:** There is no default automatic downloading mechanism - you must first select the destination and then initiate the file transfer(s). If you didn't manually download the files from the iPad, they won't be on your Mac.

To avoid this in the future, I suggest you save your documents using [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/), for example, or into [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com), [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/intl/en_US/drive/start/index.html?utm_medium=ha&utm_source=en-oa-na-us-bk&utm_campaign=en), [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) and other apps Pages can access in iOS, and which can be retrieved by OSX and Windows. This will guarantee that an important doc is available whenever needed. I use all these technologies on a mixed environment of iOS devices, Macs & PCs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. If you are saying the iPad has to be connected to see these files, that doesn't solve my problem. I exported the files as Word Doc's before, when the iPad was connected. The iPad isn't connected right now and I don't have it with me. I don't see the File Sharing section (I'm using iTunes 11).

Comment: My point is that you would have had to deliberately choose a location to save the files, then click an OK button to transfer them to your Mac. There is no automatic file transfer when you connect the iPad.

Comment: ...and when the iPad is not connected, you cannot see the File Sharing section.

Comment: I don't recall a location being specified when I exported from the iPad as a docx. Have you verified this? The file went wherever iTunes stores the other Pages files on my Laptop, which is exactly what I want to find out.

Comment: I'll reiterate: there is no default action to download all Pages documents from the iPad to your Mac as soon as it is connected. You MUST initiate the process, AND specify the destination for the files. When you export as .docx (or .pdf or pages) from Pages.app into iTunes on the iPad, it makes these files visible when the iPad is connected to iTunes on the Mac, but does not transfer them. I'll edit my answer to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @MattAsher ill try to make a very short answer so that it makes more sense.